# Android Studio ругается, что у меня некорректно введен тег цвета, хотя я его не использую даже

Tags: android, исключения, color

Есть разметка для скругления углов для элемент. В проекте размещается в директории `drawable` называется `rounded_button_today.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="10dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

НО появляется ошибка сообщающая что у меня цвет должен начинаться с # но у меня в принципе нет цвета, что не так?:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Color value 'C:\Users\VorobeyAlex\AndroidStudioProjects\LoginApp\app\src\main\res\drawable\rounded_button_today' must start with #
```

Comment: куда вы этот `drawable` присваиваете? и собсно у чего вы скругляете углы? у вас ни заполнения ни обводки нет, не у чего скруглять углы...

Comment: Я хочу скруглить кнопку. 
Но для другой кнопки похожая разметка, только с указанным цветом, работает корректно

Comment: Скруглить вы можиете таким кодом только углы `shape`, но для этого у него должно быть не только скругление но и что то у чего эти углы будут - заливка, градиент и/или рамка. А уж на кнопке или на какой другой вьюхе этот `drawable` будет потом использоваться не важно.

Comment: воооот вообще не поверишь что мне помогло!) 
название файла состоит из двух '_', если один из них убрать, то все работает корректно))))

Comment: Если Instant Run (появившийся в Android Studio 2.0) не отключен, то и не такие чудеса могут быть(

Comment: вот если б я случайно не изменил бы имя, то никогда бы не догадался об этом)

Answer (score 2):

Все что помогло - это переименования файла. 
Как я понял файл состоявший из двух символов нижнего подчеркивания выдавал такую ошибку)

Comment: Нужно было чистить кеш, можно хоть 10 нижних подчеркиваний, скорее всего вина тому инстант ран